# Pandas: how to filter all rows that correlate to a value?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have a dataframe that looks like this and three lists that contains the information whether the PDB (strucure) is old or new:

```
>>> my_df
   PDB1  PDB2  RMSD  Pair
0  A     B     0.2   A-B
1  A     C     0.1   A-C
2  A     D     0.3   A-D
3  B     C     0.3   B-C
4  C     D     0.4   C-D  
5  E     F     0.3   E-F
6  E     G     0.4   E-G
7  F     G     0.2   F-G

all_pdb = [A, B, C, D, E, F, G]
old = [A, B, C]
new = [D, E, F, G]
```

The DF compares two structures (PDB1 and PDB2) and has a column for the similarty value (RMSD) and a Pair column.

The  goal is to keep the mimunim representative amount of samples from studied ensemble while keeping the older structures over the newer ones. For example:

Keep A while dropping B, C and D and then keep E while dropping F and G since there is no old structure that represents them.

Using the structures A and E as examples, I've been able to retrieve both structures, while filtering them out of the dataframe, resulting in a dataframe like so:

```
>>> my_df
   PDB1  PDB2  RMSD  Pair
0  B     C     0.3   B-C
1  C     D     0.4   C-D  
2  F     G     0.2   F-G
```

The problem is that I'm also retrieving B, C and F structures.

This is what the code looks like right now:

```py
pdbs_to_keep = []

all_pdb = [A, B, C, D, E, F, G]

while df.empty == False:

    for x in all_pdb:

#Check whether x is in either column

        if (x in list(df['PDB1']) or x in list(df['PDB2'])):

#Make a filter selecting all rows with x in either column and delete them from the DF

            filter = df[(df['PDB1'] == str(x)) | (df['PDB2'] == str(x))]
            df = df[~df['Pair'].isin(filter['Pair'])]

#Add x to the list of structures to keep

            pdbs_to_keep.append(x)
    break
```

I expect pdbs_to_keep to contain olny A and E, but it contains all of the structures, except for D and G since the row in which they appear (with C and F respectively) are dropped before they can be added.

```
Expected result:
>>>pdbs_to_keep
>>>[A, E]

Actual result:
>>>pdbs_to_keep
>>>[A, B, C, E, F]
```

I know that the problem is that I'm only dropping the pairs that contain the analyzed structure (A or E) and not the ones that contain the related structures (B, C, D, F and G) but I can't get it to work like I want it to.

I apologize if the explanation is confusing, english is not my mother tongue. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hey buddy, can you show your expected output?

Comment: sure! I've updated the question including the expected and the actual results

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```py
# Logic
for pdb in all_pdb:
    lst = df[df['PDB1'] == pdb]['PDB2'].unique()
    all_pdb = [x for x in all_pdb if x not in lst]
```

```py
# Result
print(all_pdb)
['A', 'E']
```